# How can I set a session key from inside a GraphQL resolver in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, authentication, graphql, nestjs

I'm discovering Nest.js and I want to setup a cookie based authentication system with GraphQL.

I already installed express-session middleware, here is the configuration:

**main.ts**

```
 app.use(
    session({
      store: new redisStore({
        client: redis
      } as any),
      name: 'qid',
      secret: SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: !isDev,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 365
      }
    })
  )
```

it works fine because when I do :

```
 app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
      // Debug purpose
      req.session.userId = '42'
      next()
    })
```

The cookie is added.

Right now I have two mutations, **register** and **login**.
In the login mutation (or in the userService), after I found a user I want to do something like `req.session.userId = user.id` but I can't find a way to do this.

I tried to add `@Context() ctx` to my mutation.
If I console log ctx, it contains everything I expect (req.session.id for example)

But if I do `ctx.req.session.userId = 'something'`, the cookie is not set!

Here is my mutation:

**user.resolver.ts**

```
@Mutation('login')
  async login(
    @Args('email') email: string,
    @Args('password') password: string,
    @Context() ctx: any
  ) {
    console.log(ctx.req.session.id) // Show the actual session id
    ctx.req.session.userId = 'something' // Do not set any cookie
    return await this.userService.login(email, password)
  }
}
```

I am totally lost and I really need help, I'd love to understand what's happening. I know I'm probably doing this totally wrong but I'm new to both Nest and GraphQL..

Thank you guys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem after many days ... and it was...

GraphQL Playground -> Settings -> add "request.credentials": "include" (and no "omit")

Hope it will help someone..

Answer (score 1):

for this, it's better to do the configuration in the GraphQL config file instead of the client side

> **graphql.config.ts**

```
import { ApolloDriverConfig, ApolloDriver } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { join } from 'path';

export const GraphQLConfig: ApolloDriverConfig = {
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  debug: true,
  autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
  playground: {
    settings: {
      'editor.theme': 'light', // use value dark if you want a dark theme in the playground
      'request.credentials': 'include',
    },
  },
};
```

and assign the config file to the module directory

> **user.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { GraphQLConfig } from 'src/config/graphql.config';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/entity/user.entity';
import { UserResolver } from './user.resolver';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot(GraphQLConfig),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserResolver],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

and it will automatically enable credentials value to be "include" from "omit"